# Getting Access Denied when calling the PutObject operation with bucket-level permission

Tags: amazon-s3

I followed the example on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-s3 for how to grant a user access to just one bucket.

I then tested the config using the W3 Total Cache Wordpress plugin. The test failed.

I also tried reproducing the problem using

```
aws s3 cp --acl=public-read --cache-control='max-age=604800, public' ./test.txt s3://my-bucket/
```

and that failed with

```
upload failed: ./test.txt to s3://my-bucket/test.txt A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Why can't I upload to my bucket?

Comment: Quick note based on the above comment for Serverless Framework users (I can't comment due to rep). Your AWS bucket arn `arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName/*` should only be used when referencing the resource in `serverless.yml`. Only used the bucket name in the request `{ "Bucket": "YourBucketName" }`.

Answer (score 320):

To answer my own question:

The example policy granted PutObject access, but I also had to grant PutObjectAcl access.

I had to change

```
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:DeleteObject"
```

from the example to:

```
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:PutObjectAcl",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:GetObjectAcl",
"s3:DeleteObject"
```

You also need to make sure your bucket is configured for clients to set a public-accessible ACL by unticking these two boxes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why Amazon's own documentation is off. You might want to include "s3:AbortMultipartUpload" as well so that an aborted upload can be properly cleared.

Comment: samples for S3 policies placed here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html

Comment: btw it doesn't work for me. boto3 interaction, even with s3fullaccess policy I'm gettin "AccessDenied for PutObject"

Comment: OMG it should be made as ROLE but not as Policy. When I have created Role for S3 with the same content like policy - IT WORK

Comment: In my case its working with AWS cli, but it is not wrokign with boto

Comment: thank you! It seems that "s3:DeleteObject" is not necessary

Comment: I had S3 full access but was missing the Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects. Thank you!

Comment: Sir you're a life saver! I stuck for several hours and finally run into your lovely answer. After unticking those 2 boxes, everything works fine. Honestly, the error should have provided more details instead of a simple "Access denied"...

Comment: I had all of these things and still could not PutObject - it was a policy in the endpoint for the VPC the lambda used, the specific bucket had to be allowed there, hopefully this helps someone not spend hours debugging like I had to! :D

Comment: Note that when using versioned objects you additionally need the permission `s3:PutObjectVersionAcl`

Answer (score 108):

I was having a similar problem. I was not using the ACL stuff, so I didn't need `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

In my case, I was doing (in [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) YML):

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - s3:PutObject
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName"
```

Instead of:

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - s3:PutObject
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName/*"
```

Which adds a `/*` to the end of the bucket ARN.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I needed the one with /*

Comment: this was the case for me also

Comment: Same here, thanks for the tip. I was integrating Sentry on-premise `filestore.backend: s3` endpoint

Comment: I too had to add the "/*"

Comment: It helped me too.

Comment: Yup adding a `/*` at the end did the trick

Comment: this helped my case where I got the name of the `bucket` slightly wrong in the `Resource`

Answer (score 50):

If you have set public access for bucket and if it is still not working, edit bucket policy and paste following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketnamehere",
                "arn:aws:s3:::yourbucketnamehere/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Change yourbucketnamehere in above code with name of your bucket.

Comment: Worked for me, I created a new S3 bucket, made it fully public.  Its writeable put_object, but fails when doing put_object w/ ACL= option.  Odd ?

Comment: Note that when using versioned objects you additionally need the permission `s3:PutObjectVersionAcl`

Comment: When creating in IAM, i got an error and had to remove `"Principal": "*"`

Comment: Does work. Still gives me, `The bucket does not allow ACLs`

Comment: @Cerin this has nothing to do with above rule, enable ACLs in permission tabs of S3 object.

Answer (score 25):

In my case the problem was that I was uploading the files with "--acl=public-read" in the command line.
However that bucket has public access blocked and is accessed only through CloudFront.

Comment: This was a neat trick. reminds me to always ask what those args do :facepalm

Comment: Same. Why didn't AWS show a more specific error message in this case.

Comment: If this had higher number of votes, I would've saved 45 mins of my life :')

Answer (score 16):

I was just banging my head against a wall just trying to get S3 uploads to work with large files. Initially my error was:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

Then I tried copying a smaller file and got:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I could list objects fine but I couldn't do anything else even though I had `s3:*` permissions in my Role policy. I ended up reworking the policy to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm able to upload any file. Replace `my-bucket` with your bucket name. I hope this helps somebody else that's going thru this.

Comment: This gives:  Missing required field Principal :(

Comment: I am also getting the following error: Missing required field Principal

Comment: how do you do this in yml

Comment: Beware: this will give your IAM User/role access to list the keys in all buckets. Use with care; ideally avoid ever using `"Resource": "*"`.

Comment: Add -- "Principal": "*", -- below "Effect": "Allow", to solve the issue with the missing required field

Comment: Adding these both resources worked for me :) Thank you!!
"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"

Answer (score 14):

In case this help out anyone else, in my case, I was using a CMK (it worked fine using the default aws/s3 key)

I had to go into my encryption key definition in IAM and add the programmatic user logged into boto3 to the list of users that "can use this key to encrypt and decrypt data from within applications and when using AWS services integrated with KMS.".

Comment: This helped me. Thanks! Same error as permissions, but was in fact the encryption.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue uploading to an S3 bucket protected with KWS encryption.
I have a minimal policy that allows the addition of objects under a specific s3 key.

I needed to add the following KMS permissions to my policy to allow the role to put objects in the bucket. (Might be slightly more than are strictly required)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:ListKeys",
                "kms:GenerateRandom",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:HeadBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:ImportKeyMaterial",
                "kms:ListKeyPolicies",
                "kms:ListRetirableGrants",
                "kms:GetKeyPolicy",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext",
                "kms:ListResourceTags",
                "kms:ReEncryptFrom",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:GetParametersForImport",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GetKeyRotationStatus",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:ReEncryptTo",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:<MY-REGION>:<MY-ACCOUNT>:key/<MY-KEY-GUID>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
            <The S3 actions>
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY-BUCKET-NAME>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY-BUCKET-NAME>/<MY-BUCKET-KEY>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I copied the permissions from the default managed `aws/s3` key to an IAM policy attached to a role (not in the KMS policy), and it works well. The only actions I needed against the KMS ARNs were: `kms:Encrypt`, `kms:Decrypt`, `kms:ReEncrypt*`, `kms:GenerateDataKey*`, `kms:DescribeKey`. Then just the standard S3 permissions.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue. My bucket was private and had KMS encryption. I was able to resolve this issue by putting in additional KMS permissions in the role. The following list is the bare minimum set of roles needed.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowAttachmentBucketWrite",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
            "arn:aws:kms:kms-key-arn"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-file-encryption-kms-key/

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same error message for a mistake I made:
Make sure you use a correct s3 uri such as: `s3://my-bucket-name/`

(If my-bucket-name is at the root of your aws s3 obviously)

I insist on that because when copy pasting the s3 bucket from your browser you get something like `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-bucket-name/?region=my-aws-regiontab=overview`

Thus I made the mistake to use `s3://buckets/my-bucket-name` which raises:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied`

Answer (score 4):

Error :  An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

I solved the issue by passing Extra Args parameter as PutObjectAcl is disabled by company policy.

s3_client.upload_file('./local_file.csv', 'bucket-name', 'path', **ExtraArgs={'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256'}**)

Comment: I add "--sse" with aws cli and it's worked nice, thx

Answer (score 4):

I got this error too: `ERROR    AccessDenied: Access Denied`

I am working in a NodeJS app that was trying to use the s3.putObject method.  I got clues from reading the many other answers above, so I went to the S3 Bucket, clicked on the Permission tab, then scrolled down to the Bucket Policy section and noticed there was a condition required for access.

[image: Condition in the Bucket Policy]

So I added a ServerSideEncryption attribute to my params for the putObject call.

[image: Added ServerSideEncryption attribute to params]

This finally worked for me.  No other changes, such as any encryption of the message, are required for the putObject to work.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to one post above, (except I was using admin credentials) to get S3 uploads to work with large 50M file.

Initially my error was:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied
```

I switched the multipart_threshold to be above the 50M

```
aws configure set default.s3.multipart_threshold 64MB
```

and I got:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I checked bucket public access settings and all was allowed.
So I found that [public access can be blocked on account level for all S3 buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/block-public-access/):

[image: S3 can block public ACL on account level]

Answer (score 2):

I also solved it by adding the following KMS permissions to my policy to allow the role to put objects in this bucket (and this bucket alone):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can also test your policy configurations before applying them with the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/). This came in handy to me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had an ECS task with roles attached to it to access S3, but I tried to create a new user for my task to access SES as well. Once I did that I guess I overwrote some permissions somehow.

Basically when I gave SES access to the user my ECS lost access to S3.

My fix was to attach the SES policy to the ECS role together with the S3 policy and get rid of the new user.

What I learned is that ECS needs permissions in 2 different stages, when spinning up the task and for the task's everyday needs. If you want to give the containers in the task access to other AWS resources you need to make sure to attach those permissions to the ECS task.

My code fix in terraform:

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "AmazonSESFullAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_ses_access" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.app_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.AmazonSESFullAccess.arn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I was using expired auth keys. Generated new ones and boom.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that my source (an ec2 instance) had an IAM role attached that didn't allow any write actions, so even though the bucket policy was correct, I couldn't write anything to anywhere from it. I solved it by adding this policy to the IAM role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination-bucket/destination-path/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue so checked the permission tab in the AWS bucket. The public access was blocked which was causing the issue in my case so I unchecked the option and it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmYI4.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that your awsClient config makes use of credentials provider and is finding the correct credentials
2. Verify that the assumed role has a policy that grants it s3:PutObject on the bucket and the contents of the bucket /*
3. Verify the name of the bucket is correct
4. Verify the ACL action on the PutObjectRequest is granted in your policy and is applicable to your usecase

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified your own customer managed KMS key for S3 encryption you also need to provide the flag `--server-side-encryption aws:kms`, for example:

`aws s3api put-object --bucket bucket --key objectKey --body /path/to/file --server-side-encryption aws:kms`

If you do not add the flag `--server-side-encryption aws:kms` the cli displays an `AccessDenied` error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by granting complete s3 access to Lambda from policies. Make a new role for Lambda and attach the policy with complete S3 Access to it.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my access, access of S3 bucket was not provided to the IAM role attached with the EC2 instance I was trying to access so please verify once if S3 access is provided to that EC2 or not.

Hope it works for someone.

Answer (score -1):

In addition, I have set the permission for the group to which the user belongs to.
[image]