# Deployment Issue with Django Web App on AWS – Error during 'collectstatic' to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

### Context

I have successfully developed a Django full web application and am currently in the deployment phase. My database is hosted on an AWS RDS Postgres instance. As part of the deployment process, I am attempting to collect static files using the command:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

with the intention of storing them in an AWS S3 Bucket.

### Issue:

However, I am encountering the following error during the 'collectstatic' process:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessControlListNotSupported) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket does not allow ACLs`

### Error details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line   
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 378, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage\base.py", line 38, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\storages\backends\s3.py", line 494, in _save
    obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=params, Config=self.transfer_config)
  File "C:\Users\xmedi\OneDrive\Escritorio\Projects\Personal\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 731, in object_upload_fileobj
    return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 642, in upload_fileobj
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\upload.py", line 764, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\myapp\venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\postgram\venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 1009, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessControlListNotSupported) when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket does not allow ACLs
```

### Code snipped:

###### setting.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import environ

# Environment
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #Django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #Local apps
    'posts',
    'users',

    #Third party apps
    'storages',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # Custom middleware
    'postgram.middleware.ProfileCompletionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'postgram.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') 
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'postgram.wsgi.application'

# Database in AWS RDS
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        'NAME': env('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': env("DATABASE_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("DATABASE_HOST"),
        'PORT': env("DATABASE_PORT"),
    }
}
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField' 


# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

#######
# AWS #
#######
USE_S3 = env('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # AWS settings
    AWS_S3_VERITY = True
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
    AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME = 's3v4',
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # S3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
################################################################

LOGIN_URL = '/users/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' 
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = LOGIN_URL
```

### Configurations:

###### S3 bucket configurations:

[image: Configuration 1]
[image: Configuration 2]

###### User group permissions:

[image]

### Solutions attempted:

1. [[Django][AWS S3] botocore.exceptions.clienterror an error occurred (accessdenied) when calling the PutObject operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788998/djangoaws-s3-botocore-exceptions-clienterror-an-error-occurred-accessdenied)
2. https://aws.plainenglish.io/s3-error-accesscontrollistnotsupported-358cc5b27e15
3. https://zoveloper.medium.com/3-aws-s3-bucket-error-786b1fc8d42

### Request for Assistance:

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to resolve this 'collectstatic' error and successfully deploy my Django web application on AWS.

Comment: `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'` Try it without this line.  You have it set to `None` above, but you override it with this line below.