# Django Web App - Static Files Forbidden 403 Error when Retrieving from AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

#### Context

I have successfully developed and deployed a Django web application on AWS, leveraging an AWS RDS Postgres instance for the database. In the deployment process, I utilized the 'collectstatic' command to gather static files, and with the help of the community in a **[previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753374/deployment-issue-with-django-web-app-on-aws-error-during-collectstatic-to-s3)**, I overcame challenges related to that stage.

#### Current Challenge

Following the successful 'collectstatic' process and upload to an S3 Bucket, I am encountering an issue wherein the static files cannot be retrieved by the HTML within the Django app.

```
GET https://postgram-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
GET https://postgram-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 
GET https://postgram-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/postgram_logo.png 403 (Forbidden)
```

[image]

#### Troubleshooting Steps Taken

1. Successfully executed 'collectstatic' and uploaded static files to the S3 Bucket.
2. Checked AWS S3 Bucket permissions and confirmed that the IAM role associated with the Django app has the necessary permissions.
3. Validated credentials by making a request through Postman, and the static files were successfully received in the response (refer to the attached image).
   [image]

#### Relevant Configuration

###### AWS S3 Bucket configuration

[image]

###### IAM role configuration

[image]

### Code Snippet

###### setting.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') 
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

##########
# AWS S3 #
##########
USE_S3 = env('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # AWS settings
    AWS_S3_VERITY = True
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
    AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME = 's3v4'
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # S3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
```

### Request for Assistance:

I am seeking guidance on resolving the 403 Forbidden error and allowing the Django app to retrieve static files from the AWS S3 Bucket. Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

## Solved

Updated the bucket policy in the permission tab and worked.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the bucket policy?  you turned off ACLs for the bucket (as is recommended); now you have to define public access in the bucket policy.  Have you?

Comment: Static files are requested by the _client_, not the server. Are your users authorized to access your S3 bucket?

Comment: Updated bucket policy and now it is working!