# Lambda function issue when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I need your help on this issue on which am always getting issue after many more solutions adaptations.

I tried to resolve this issue with answers posted on the below links, but nothing has worked on my side:

> [Getting Access Denied when calling the PutObject operation with bucket-level permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36272286/10663537)
> https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-s3-access-denied-when-calling-putobject

Am developing the lambda function deployed as docker image which has to save some data in files on S3.

The IAM Policy has permission to `ListBucket`, `GetObject`, `PutObject`, but in production this don't work: I tried to apply policy on bucket, but I am getting the same results (the below issue). I finally decided to make the bucket public, unfortunately this is also unsuccessful.

[image: AWS S3 PutObject Issue]

> Policy on the bucket:
>
> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "Statement1",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": "*",
>             "Action": "s3:*",
>             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-xxx/*"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

Can you please help me to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the bucket have a bucket policy?

Comment: @Paolo yes it does!

Comment: Well, that's most likely the issue then. Can you show the policy

Comment: @Paolo the question has been updated!

Comment: That bucket policy is dangerous (you should delete it asap) but it's not the cause of your AccessDenied problem. Double check the IAM role and policy for your Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

First off, fix that Bucket policy: you're allowing any authenticated AWS principal to do anything to the contents of your Bucket.  If I had its name, I could delete all of your data right now.  The "Principal" field should name only those principals that you need to access the Bucket.

As for your original question, I suspect that your Bucket is encrypted using a KMS CMK?  In that case, your caller needs permission to use the CMK as well. Put something like this in your CMK's key policy to allow you to write to the Bucket:

```
{
  "Action": [
    "kms:GenerateDataKey"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/your_lambda_Role"
  },
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

See https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-access-default-encryption for more details.